# Special characters in scrapy rules

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a news site: https://www.larazon.es/etiquetas/noticias/meta/politica#.p:3;
I tested first the response with the following script and I see it works:

```
class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = 'crawler_larazon'
    allowed_domains = ['larazon.es']
    start_urls = ['https://www.larazon.es/etiquetas/noticias/meta/politica#.p:3']


    def parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

However, when adding my selectors and rules I'm not getting any response. I'm new with scrapy but I have 2 assumptions of what might be happening:

- The special characters on the linkextractor url are messing up my scraper. I checked and tested some regex but nothing seems to work

```
    rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'etiquetas/noticias/meta/politica#.p:[2-3];'),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]
```

- the page takes a while to load so I'm not sure if there's a timeout that needs to be configured

```
class StackCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawler_larazon'
    allowed_domains = ['larazon.es']
    start_urls = ['https://www.larazon.es/etiquetas/noticias/meta/politica']

    rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'etiquetas/noticias/meta/politica#.p:[2-3];'),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        questions = response.xpath('//h2[@class="news__new__title news__new__title"]')
        for question in questions:
            item = StackItem()
            item['url'] = question.xpath(
                'a/@href').extract()[0]
            item['source'] = self.allowed_domains[0]
            yield item
```

any ideas of what I'm missing?
Many thanks!

Comment: ,I've check the response from the website when you use "#.p:3'" at the end of the url, the server is doing a query to the database as you can see the request looks like .. [complete in http://collabedit.com/bxuyd ] you are overloading the server curl 'https://www.larazon.es/news-portlet/html/teaser-viewer-portlet/teaser_page.jsp?portletItem=&refPreferenceId=teaserviewerportlet_WAR_newsportlet_INSTANCE_Wx7z&portletId=&contentId=0&categoryIds=105838&date=20190908132625&teasertotalcount=999&firstItem=16&lastItem=31&globalFirstItem=0&globalLastItem=999&globalLastIndex=2&scopeGroupId=10810&company.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html